# How to perform a MarkLogic search for documents in one or more collections

Tags: search, collections, xquery, marklogic

I have documents in collections based upon the mime-type image it's describing: image/jpg, image/png, image/gif.

I would like to be able specify a `$mime-type` as `"image"` or `"image/jpg"` so that I can search for a document across all image types or across a specific subtype.

```
let $mime-type-pattern := fn:concat($mime-type, "*")
let $mime-type-collection-uris := cts:collection-match($mime-type-pattern)
```

Searching for the `$mime-type` `"image"` will return the URIs `("image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif")`.  I would like to be able to search for documents in any of these collections.

Searching for the `$mime-type` `"image/jpg"` will return the URI `("image/jpg")`.  I would then only be searching for documents the "image/jpg" collection.

What is the structure of the `search:options` I need to create to search with the Search API?

Comment: Can you easily tag all of your image/jpg (or image/foo) as also in the image collection?  That would make this easier, perhaps.

Comment: I could tag them both with the type and subtype separately and perhaps simplify elsewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `cts:collection-query` inside the `<additional-query>` option which is nested inside the `<options>` node:

```
search:search("foo",
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <additional-query>
      {cts:collection-query($mime-type-collection-uris)}
    </additional-query>
  </options>)
```

This will constrain the search to the collections in `$mime-type-collection-uris`.

Comment: Thanks Evan.  Worked like a charm.  Just one question.  If my mime-type doesn't result in any collections, $mime-type-collection-uris is an empty set.  It seems like cts:collection-query defaults to searching any/all collections if it's passed an empty set.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Good question. Based on my testing, no, I think it will only match documents that are associated with any of the specified collection URIs. If you don't pass any collection URIs (an empty sequence), then it will match no documents. Are you seeing different behavior? You can test this with `cts:search(collection(), cts:collection-query(()))`, which returns an empty sequence. But I'll go check to make sure the Search API isn't doing something different...

Comment: Yeah, the Search API behaves consistently (returning no results). You can test this by replacing `$mime-type-collection-uris` with `()` in the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

Evan's answer looks good. Joe has probably already thought about this, but I wanted to mention a potential design problem with using collection in this way.

A collection is just a flat string. So while the mime-type alone is fine, you have the potential for naming conflict with some other collection that you add later on. You could add some protection by giving some namespace-like structure to the collection names, like `mime-type=image/jpg` for example. That could also speed up the collection-match in some situations.

In most cases I would recommend using an element instead of a collection, simply to avoid this pitfall. But with images this element would have to go into the properties fragment, which might cost more than it is worth if you have no other properties to store.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the suggestion.  I'll review the design to see if it makes sense to refactor. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Over qconole, search based on collection name -

```
fn:collection("collection-name");
```

get the collection name assigned to a URI -

```
xdmp:document-get-collection("uri of document");
```